# Enable gzip compression prestashop 1.7.2.4

Tags: caching, gzip, pagespeed, prestashop-1.7, gtmetrix

Gtmetrix shows that i have to enable gzip compression even i've already did those steps:

1- Gzip is enabled in my hosting web server configuration https://snag.gy/c2VQ1s.jpg

2- The 'apache optimization' is enabled and then prestashop add the following to my .htaccess file.

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType font/otf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
```

```
Header unset Etag
```

FileETag none

```
<IfModule mod_filter.c>AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript font/ttf application/x-font-ttf font/otf application/x-font-otf font/opentype image/svg+xml
</IfModule>
```

I need some help, please.